# How to draw a distribution plot in seaborn?

Tags: python, plot, seaborn

It comes out well in the histplot, but it doesn't draw well in the distplot.

`sns.histplot(df[target])`
[image: the histplot looks okay]

`sns.distplot(df[target])`
[image: the distplot is just a flat line]

Comment: maybe you need to zoom in on the Density axis (due to the huge magnitute of the x axis!)

Comment: Also, update seaborn to 0.11.2. `distplot` is deprecated. Use `sns.histplot` or `sns.displot`.

Answer (score 1):

Your x range of values is huge! `sns.dist()` plots the distribution probability meaning the sum will equal to 1. So essentially with this huge magnitude of your x values, you'll have very small probability values. This and your y graph range is -1 to 1. If you change your y range, you should get something closer to what you'd expect to see.

So change your y scale to something like:

```
sns.distplot(df[target])
plt.ylim(0, .1**27)
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try `sns.displot(data=df, x="target", kde=True)`

or `sns.displot(data=df, x="target", kind="kde")`